# Post containing slander against sahaba?

Tags: discussion

I am seeing that many Shia favouring posts are upvoted and even a [hadith authenticity (of sunni view ) is being downvoted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16275/hadith-authenticity-regarding-rafidah-sunni-view-only). Also what to do regarding posts which slander the "Sahabas" quoting texts which are considered to be unreliable by Sunnis and reliable by Shias?

As we have a hadith that speaking slander of sahabas or any Muslims is haram.

Should we allow quoting secondary non hadith texts which speak ill of the righteous sahabas

Comment: Downvoting is far more likely to represent a poor question than it is to represent partisan voting.  I would suggest you go through the advice in the help page "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" before resorting to accusations and insinuations.

Comment: @goldPseudo This holds true only in a mature site with strong cohesive community and not like this site where people dont even care to vote, giving the partisan users a chance to show poor voting

Comment: forummer, can you please clarify whether you are asking specifically about _slander_ (as the title would suggest), or about _speaking ill_ of the sahaba, which may not necessarily be slanderous?  It seems that the title of the question doesn't match the body.  Maybe quoting the actual hadeeth would be helpful too.

Answer (score 8):

Reasonably, criticism of Sahaba must be distinguished from slander.

'Slander' according to *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* is defined as:

> a *false* spoken statement about someone, intended to damage the good
>   opinion that people have of that person.

Therefore, if a statement provides even *an apparently factual or reasoned* criticism of some Sahaba or even expresses a general scholarly point of view held by a group of Islamic scholars in regards with Sahaba, the position will not fall under the definition of 'slander' as it doesn't indicate ill slanderous intentions *unless* they are firmly proven wrong and the non-scholarly ill intentions behind them demonstrated.

But generally as for disagreements on merits of Sahaba you should note that they are some of the very issues that deeply divide different sects of Islam. A sahaba that is considered 'righteous' by one sect may be denounced as 'unrighteous', 'wrong' or even outright 'treacherous' by another.

Therefore members of each sect have the right to express their beliefs so long as they are referenced and backed up by their official sources. If you don't agree with them, then the best you can do is to question their opinion by providing counter arguments.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't the hadeeth say that it's haram to speak ill of sahaba?  Not just specifically to slander them?  However, I guess not all sects see this hadeeth as authentic.

Comment: @DavidWallace, you answered your own question, also sects may differ on who can be regarded as a real or righteous sahaba!

Comment: that defination of slander exactly fits to what is being done here. A shia book which less then 20% of Muslims consider reliable is used to slander a personality which is authentically proven to be correct from their sources.

Comment: @forummer, if you think so, then post an answer and make your case. If you can convince that the opinion is a false slanderous opinion then they community make take due considerations. But please note that truthfulness of an opinion is determined by supportive proofs and reasons, and much less by the number of those who support it!

Comment: +1 I think it's essential to draw a line between expressing a view reasonably (which may conflict with other's beliefs) and *attacking* another's beliefs. The difference is in context (eg is it a question or an answer or in chat) and tone (eg is the language inflammatory or 'ad hominem').