# Suspended in chat on trying to make the other user compliant to etiquette

Tags: discussion, chat

I and another user @infatuated were suspended in chat after I tried to make a case that we should not speak ill of sahabas , but she hesitated and did not agree with me, this caused the only mod to suspend both of us for 7 days and one can easily see [the chat log](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17624415#17624415) there were no abuses thrown by me at least. And the post of other user were flagged too, yet I ended up being suspended in chat due to the other user. Hence please remove the block.

Comment: The chat log has the most egregious instances of abusive messages removed. Moderators from across the network can review those parts too, but claiming the log doesn't show any abuses on your part is just disingenuous. Even the [still-standing messages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/126529/ahlelbayt?tab=recent) show strong evidence of _you_ being argumentative. Also the express reason for the suspensions has nothing to do with the reasons you suggest and there were at least 3 mods monitoring the situation not 1 (and more have reviewed since).

Answer (score 2):

Are you seriously suggesting [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17624209#17624209) kind of talk is constructive?

- > you quoted a dictionary defination of slander and ,see how well it defines what some shia users write.
- > Ali himself was "silent" and patronized the past 3 caliphs, so shias have nothing to stand upon.

**You needed your suspension just for that** - but for the sake of the site and the benefit it brings to those interested in Islam and the Qur'an, *please* spend less time complaining about your treatment and more time humbly considering your own actions. Especially whether you are willing to change how you interact with others who wish to be part of the community here.

The point of suspending you is not to punish you. It is to protect the community and give you a chance to cool down and consider your words more carefully before you speak again - that's why I say you "needed" your suspension rather than you "deserved" it.

Comment: Why on Earth do you expect a very new user to show an understanding quality of that of an old high rep user or moderator?! You people seem to be more interested in patronizing people by enforcing site rules than a sympathetic interest in educating them with your experience which must the true spirit of moderation instead of a dominant tendency to conceited and mechanical application of site rules which never help our community improve, as evidences by two years of this failed moderation approach!

Comment: Just as Kaveh described [the issues with moderation](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/issues-with-moderation) very recently, the problem with moderators on this site is that, 
"Their attitude is that of a judge/policeman, not that of a community builder or a respectful educator" and we can see yet another clear example of this attitude right before our eyes!

Comment: I'm personally in two minds about Kaveh's post - I upvoted his answer but not the question. Some of what he says has merit in my view but Caleb's critique is mostly correct. Regardless, your tone and choice of words on this post does your argument no favours - if you want others to take your criticism of the mods seriously you need to present it as something more constructive that a rant.

Comment: What goes around comes around! Only when moderators treat others respectfully, they can also expect users to interact with them in the same manner. Some moderators have so far badly failed in [leading by example and being gentle and respectful](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). In fact if I wanted to treat them like they treated me, I have not yet used any offensive words that they have relentlessly used against me and other users recently! I have shown much restraint in the (so far vein) hope that they may come to their conscience and act responsibly.

Comment: And stop labeling my reasonable and legitimate opinions as 'rants'! Calling people names and defaming them never whatsoever helps settling the differences, as it hasn't so far!

Comment: @JackDouglas I am not strongly opinionated here but I would like to add. A mod used the word 'Shut up' for me in chat. He was not suspended. Also I saw the same mod bullying another user from Shia sect. No repercussions for me. The question is are mods always right. Also you see the language here "Annnnd Enjoy your suspension". We are talking about professional here. Is this professional?

Comment: @muslim1 "The question is are mods always right" no - that's a different question and of course mods are not always right. My answer here is a response to the OP's assertion that "...there were no abuses thrown by me..." - imo the suspension was warranted as I say.

Comment: @JackDouglas the suspension language is a little troublesome here "Enjoy your suspension". I think it is terribly rude and unprofessional. You have to account for that as well. Basically if the mod does not have any etiquette what do you expect from a user. Anyways just my point...

Comment: @muslim1 I take your point, but this question is about what happened *before* that comment. You've laid out your stance [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1224/3208) already and it appears you don't have the community behind you. It seems likely to me that many would echo the first comment: "I agree with some of your points and disagree with some others" - in other words they are not mindlessly defending all moderation but *on balance* are grateful and supportive of the work being done. Why not try and help the moderators improve instead of calling for their removal again?

Comment: @JackDouglas nope, not calling for their removal. Again I am misunderstood wrong. I will leave it here. Basically we just have to respect each other. I brought this point just to have fair look at the suspension. If one person is childish, the other person is also arrogant and unprofessional. That's all :)

Comment: @muslim1 I am sorry I misrepresented you when I said you were calling for removal - that's the impression I got from your post but that's my fault for not reading it carefully enough. I stand by my point that this question is not about the behaviour of a moderator *after the suspension* but the correctness *of the suspension itself*. Note the OP's assertion that he was suspended in chat "due to the *other user*".

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think you even carefully and entirely *read* my post in [the relevant meta discussion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/post-containing-slander-against-sahaba/1254#1254) where my view was established (judging by the heavy upvotes) that **since sects *do not agree* on the merits of sahaba they are entitled to express their distinct views about them!** I had intentionally highlighted the part of the definition which defines 'slander' as "*a false statement* ..." and then proceeded to explain that some sects *really believe* (at least based on their own sources and documents) that some of the sahabas were not righteous or were even treacherous. Therefore the definition which characterizes slander as "*a false statement* against some one" excludes some sects negative view of sahaba.

So my just rationale was quit clear and was welcome by the community. But your failure to carefully read and *understand* my meta post unfortunately led both of us into an undeserving trouble! However as I explained in [this meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/should-content-representing-an-offical-scholarly-view-of-an-islamic-sect-critica), goldPseudo has evidently over used his moderation powers once again, as there was nothing fundamentally wrong for us to discuss a site policy even if it was done in a serious tone so far as we both of us were genuinely interested in settling a disagreement.